# How to get windows current login details

Tags: php, batch-file, active-directory, exec, phpdesktop

I have tried to get the current login name for user. i'm using windows 8.

When i execute the command as  "whoami" then i'm getting the correct login name.,

When i execute the same in exec("whoami"); then i will get the user account that have created on this system.

Any idea why its happen like that .

i'm using PHPDesktop application. Even when i run the BAT in cmd then its return correct value. But same BAT returns user account name when its run in PHP.

Even tried get_current_user()., $_ENV , $_SERVER ,

No luck.

Answer (score 1):

The user account name (= login name) is held in environment variable **USERNAME** on Windows. So you just have to get the value of this environment variable.

Open a command prompt window, just enter `set` and look on the list of environment variables output. You see now all standard environment variables on Windows like **APPDATA**, **USERNAME**, **USERPROFILE**, etc.

See Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) for a list of predefined environment variables with description.